# CloudWatch log insights query scans very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm looking for help on an issue I'm struggling with.

I have created a new log group on CloudWatch, created a few streams and up to 1500 log events in total via AWS `putLogEvents` method. When I run a simple query to return just the timestamp and message, the query takes about 20-25 seconds to scan all 1500 events which is slow compared to other log groups. The scan rate fluctuates starting from 300 records per second down to 60 records per second.

In other log groups with an even larger size (e.g. 10,000+), the query took about 5 seconds. I'm clueless as to why the query takes such a long time to scan.

Any assistance is highly appreciated, TIA.